# Why "c" option in formatoptions makes Vim hard-wrap my lists in "text" files?

Tags: vimrc, wrapping

Here is my test .vimrc:

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

set textwidth=78
let &colorcolumn = &textwidth + 1
set linebreak breakindent
set number

augroup disable_auto_wrapping
  autocmd!
  autocmd filetype * set formatoptions-=t
augroup END
```

If I open a `.txt` file, `:set fo?` returns `cq`.

If I type a regular long line, it won't be hard-wrapped. Fine.

But if a line starts with an asterisk or hyphen, Vim will hard-wrap it nevertheless.

```
this is normal line that exceeds textwidth+1 value

* and this is the same line
  if I start it with asterisk
  or hyphen
```

I know I can stop this by using `:set fo-=c`, but why is that? It seems the `c` option is completely unrelated to the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. From `:help fo-table` we get:

   ```
   c    Auto-wrap comments using 'textwidth', inserting the current comment
        leader automatically.
   ```
2. `*.txt` are given the `text` filetype, which defines the following option:

   ```
   set comments=fb:-,fb:*,n:>
   ```
3. The `*` that you use to mark up list items is recognized as a comment leader so your list is formatted as if it were a comment.

See `:help format-comment`.

Comment: This is somewhat strange they are treated as comment leaders. Even more strange this is still true for "text" files and not only "markdown".

Comment: What is "strange"? How it is done or why?

Comment: "Why" ........................

Comment: That's quite an open-ended question. The original Markdown spec never mandated a specific extension so you can have Markdown or Markdown-like markup with or without `.md`. Also, people have been using lightweight markup in `*.txt` or extension-less files for decades (hint: the ancestor of GitHub era `README.md` were `README.txt` and, before that, plain `README`). That said, I think that the use of an explicitly comment-related feature for something unrelated  with comments is more like a dirty hack than a well thought out feature.

Comment: @user90726 well it certainly wouldn't be true for markdown, * isn't a comment in markdown.